# MySql: Loading product catalog : An error was encountered loading the product catalog on windows 7

Tags: mysql

I was trying to install MySQL but am not successful, Am getting the error when loading the product catalog.
Tried different versions of MySQL, still getting the same error.

Can anyone help me with this ??

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, uninstall MySQL from Control Panel. 
Now go to the C drive and show all hidden files.
Now go to the Program Files and delete MySQL directory from there, and do the same thing in Program Data and Program File(x86).
Then try again to install MySQL. it will not show you this message again. 
It is better to do this method by turn off your internet on the system.

It worked for me... Good Luck!